# Selecionar coluna Qt ComboBox

Tags: sql, qt, combobox

Tenho um botão Conectar no mainwindow.ui

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ConectarDB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    ConectarDB.setHostName("localhost");
    ConectarDB.setDatabaseName("Banco");
    ConectarDB.setPort(3306);
    ConectarDB.setUserName("root");
    ConectarDB.setPassword("root");}
```

Ele funciona perfeitamente, mas tenho duas duvidas:

1) Como eu faria para aparecer uma mensagem confirmando que a conexão foi realizada com sucesso, dps que o botão fosse clicado?

2) Depois de conectado, eu tenho outro form com um comboBOX nele.

```
Buscar_por_CURSO::Buscar_por_CURSO(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Buscar_por_CURSO)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mBuscaCurso = new QSqlTableModel(this);
    mBuscaCurso->setTable("Cursos");
    mBuscaCurso->select();
    ui->comboBox->setModel(mBuscaCurso);
}
```

Minha table Cursos:

```
Create table Cursos(
ID_curso int not null auto_increment,
Nome_curso varchar (50),
primary key (ID_curso)
)default charset = utf8;
```

Desse jeito, o que aparece na comboBox são os **ID_curso**, mas gostaria que fosse o **Nome_curso**.

Como faço para resolver isso?

Grato desde já

Comment: Acabei utilizando `QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel; model->setQuery("select nome_curso from Cursos"); ui->comboBox->setModel(model);` para resolver o 2º problema. Mas agora eu estou pensando em utilizar o **nome_curso** selecionado na combobox para mostrar em um tableview dados de uma outra tabela que tem `foreign key (Curso_id) references Cursos (ID_Curso)`. É possivel fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Para o problema 1:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ConectarDB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    ConectarDB.setHostName("localhost");
    ConectarDB.setDatabaseName("Banco");
    ConectarDB.setPort(3306);
    ConectarDB.setUserName("root");
    ConectarDB.setPassword("root");
    **if (!ConectarDB.open()){
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", ConectarDB.lastError().text());
        return;}
    else{
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        msgBox.setText("Conexão realizada com sucesso");
        msgBox.exec();}**
}
```

Para o problema 2:

```
Buscar_por_CURSO::Buscar_por_CURSO(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Buscar_por_CURSO)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel;
    model->setQuery("select nome_curso from Cursos");
    ui->comboBox->setModel(model);
}
```